# Rollback last seeding in Laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel-5

I have run a seeder to insert new records. But I need to rollback the last seeder I have run. Is there any way to do that in Laravel ?

Answer (score 0):

Rolling back a seed cant be done.
What you could do is

```
php artisan migrate:refresh --seed
```

This will only work if in your migrate you have your down() set to droppping the existing table.